# jQuery.ajaxSetup: override error with statusCode

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code for default jQuery AJAX error handling:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    },
    statusCode : {
        404: function() {
            alert("Element not found.");
        }
    }
});
```

However, when 404 happens, BOTH functions are upcalled: first *error*, then *statusCode*, so I see 2 consecutive alerts.

How to prevent this behaviour and get *error* callback only if *statusCode* was not upcalled?

Comment: No-no. I want a specific message in case of 404, and the default one otherwise.

Comment: I'm with you @weekens. The lack of an 'else' on statusCode entries, or absent that, some way to call your statusCode handler first and allow it to suppress the generic error handler if it wants to, makes the whole statusCode option useless IMO. It's only usable if you have statusCode entries for every possible error code, not reasonable. I hope the jQuery folks reconsider this architecture.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about just checking for status code 404 in your error handler?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert("Element not found.");
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(jqXHR.status === 404) {
      alert("Element not found.");
    } else {
      alert("Error: " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    }
}
});
```